# Site Theme Error when publishing enabled?

Tags: publishing-site, publishing, theme

Hoping someone can help me. This is a SharePoint 2010 Environment.

- When trying to click on 'site theme' in the site settings menu of one of the sub-sites in a site collection that has publishing enabled.
- When I disable publishing at the site collection level the error disappears.
- The same error appears regardless of whether the sub-sites themselves have publishing enabled or disabled.

Error:

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.CodeBehind.EnhancedThemingPostOptions.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +2748
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +65
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +190
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +190
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +190
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +190
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +190
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +190
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +190
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +190
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +190
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +190
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2427
```

I have also used reflector and executed the statements in Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.CodeBehind.EnhancedThemingPostOptions.OnLoad to see if any of them return a nullreference, but no luck unfortunately.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Welcome to SharePoint! Please read [our editing guidelines](http://meta.sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/115/have-any-tips-for-editing-questions/116#116) which I've used to improve your question. These help more people to find your post, and also encourage more to answer it. You can also read [How to Ask](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/faq#howtoask) for more general guidelines.